# ERROR: Top blob 'data' produced by multiple sources

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, nvidia-digits

I have six channel image (2 RGB image concatenated). I want to train the model with these images using AlexNet. I packed the images into lmdb. 
Then I used the `OTHER` option for dataset and model, however I am getting the following error when I am creating the model .

```
ERROR: Top blob 'data' produced by multiple sources. 
Creating layer train-data
Creating Layer train-data
Top blob 'data' produced by multiple sources.
Opened lmdb /lmdb_database/train_labels
```

I am using standard [AlexNet architecture](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/blob/v4.0.0-rc.3/digits/standard-networks/caffe/alexnet.prototxt).

**Data Preparation in lmdb**

I have two images in RGB coming from two different modalities. I modified createdb.py script from siamese example to concatenate two images. Once I have the dataset then I am using the standard AlexNet Prototext to train the model

Comment: hi, i am facing the same issue. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: yeah I did solve it.

Comment: if you don't specify train or val phase. By default it will consider it as train, val and deploy phase. @AbdulJabbar

Answer (score 0):

Check your input data layers, is it possible you forgot to specify `stage`/`phase` for them? it seems like caffe is trying to use both at the same time

Comment: I am using standard AlexNet prototxt, link mentioned above. I believe the AlexNet assume that the two concatenated images are coming from both train and val. Can someone explain to me how to use multiple input. @Shai

Comment: @cpwah please describe in more detail how you prepare your data and how the input layer prototxt looks like

Comment: I have edited the question. Please let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 0):

Today I have encountered this problem too. And I found a solution. My data layer's name is 'data' and then top is 'data' too, so it has a wrong. And I change my data layer, it works.

Comment: can you share your prototxt file?